# Creating a genetics calculator in PHP, issues with wrong results

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a genetic calculator. I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $gene1 = 'BA';
    $geneA = array();
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < strlen($gene1)) $geneA[] = substr($gene1,$i++,2);

    $gene2 = 'MSBA';
    $geneB = array();
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < strlen($gene2)) $geneB[] = substr($gene2,$i++,2);

    $possabilities = array();
    foreach ($geneA as $A) {
       foreach ($geneB as $B) {
          if ($A === strtoupper($A)) $possabilities[] = $A.$B;
          else {
             if ($B === strtoupper($B)) $possabilities[] = $B.$A;
             else $possabilities[] = $A.$B;
          }
       }
    }
    print_r($possabilities);
?>
```

Which works to a degree, it pairs the genes in the array, however it isn't working properly. This pairing should just return `BABA` and `MSBA`. Instead it returns this:

`Array ( [0] => BAMS [1] => BASB [2] => BABA [3] => BAA [4] => AMS [5] => ASB [6] => ABA [7] => AA )`

Which isn't exactly ideal for my project. I thought a better idea would be to comma separate the genes like this `$gene1 = 'BA';` and `$gene2 = 'MS,BA';` and run a loop combining each gene that way, but i am unsure on how to do this properly. Can anyone shed some light on the idea at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I'm right in assuming that

- Genes are always made up of two pairs (MS, but not "M" and "S")
- Each member of `$geneA` should be matched with each member of `$geneB`

**Part 1: Resolving the error**

In this case your algorithm for splitting has a serious flaw: It always progresses just for one step in the original string (`$gene1` and `$gene2`)

```
function getGeneArray($geneString) {
    // check the argument for fitting your needs!
    if ( strlen($geneString) % 2 == 1 ) {
         die('Supplied geneString is not made of pairs!'); // better not die - handle errors according to your application methodology
    }
    // add additional error-catching (there are only certain possible base-pairs, if something else is found you should reject the string

    $genes = array();
    $i = 0;
    while ( $i < strlen($geneString) )
    {
        $genes[] = substr($geneString, $i, 2);
        $i += 2; // Here is your mistake, you just $i++
    }
    return $genes;
}
```

With this little function you a) reduce duplicates in your code and b) get a determined outcome (no wrong genes)

**Part 2: Making code document itself**

Looking at your code it becomes clear, that uppercase-gene-pairs must come befor lowercase pairs, I try to communicate that with the code by using an extra function with a clear name.

```
function combinePairs($A, $B) {
    // uppercase genes build the string first, which means B must be uppercase to come first and A cant be uppercase
    if (strtoupper($A) !== $A && strotoupper($B) === $B) {
        return $B.$A;
    } 
    return $A.$B;
}
```

**Part 3: Plugging it together**

```
$geneA = getGeneArray($gene1);
$geneB = getGeneArray($gene2);

$possibilities = array();
foreach ($geneA as $A) {
    foreach ($geneB as $B) {
        $possibilities[] = combinePairs($A, $B);
    }
}

print_r($possibilities);
```

**Final Note**

As a programmer you want to cater the needs of your client or input source, so of course you can split your genes with commas. Try to use the format most usable for your application and client input. In this case you could easily optain an array by using `explode()` [(explode in the manual)](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php)

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic and gives me something to work with, thank you so much! Can you give advice at all on if i used something like "WTba" crossed to "WTba" and how to establish that 2 recessive genes (lowercase) would become BA. For example, the actual outcome of that would be WT, BA and WTba

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm no genetic expert but I have something in mind like mendel rules ...  but let's start at the beginning: after calculating all possibilities you wanna do a next-step function with the result from your script? does it take into account any chances or should it just reflect the possibilities? could you provide some example data?